# Select с объединением регистра в выводе, help

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

с sql знаком совсем недавно и столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:
Есть запрос:

```
Select distinct user_name from table
Where (date between '28.11.2018 00:00:00 and 28.11.2018 05:00:00')
And type = 'login' and name like '%[^0-9 a-z]%' collate Cyrillic_General_100_cs_as
Order by name;
```

Выделенная строчка неправильная, ее нужно заменить. 
Необходимо вывести список имён так, чтобы одинаковые имена, но с разным регистром выводились как одно ( без повтора типо 1) `petrov` 2) `PETROV`
Думаю, нужно, чтобы верхний регистр приравнивался к нижнему и выводился с заменой.

Comment: для начала `' and '` сделайте в датах

Comment: @NickProskuryakov никогда не стоит исправлять код, кроме его форматирования. Вы можете удалить исходную проблему вопроса.

Comment: у вас если для столбца локаль задана CI, то дистинкт и так выберет только один вариант имени.

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
select distinct
  name, no from
  (select
    upper(ename) name,
    max(empno) over (partition by ename) no
  from EMP e0
  ) e1
```